# Difference between function names from Drupal Devel

Tags: debugging

The devel module in drupal allows us to print variable data using functions like:
kpr,krumo,dpm,dsm
Can anyone please explain how different is each function from the other

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help you a bit:

- `dpm($var)` or `dsm($var)` - displays the information about a variable in the form of system messages using [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/).
- `dvm($var)` - displays the information about a variable in the form of system messages using [var_dump($var)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).
- `dpr($var, $return = false)` - displays the information about a variable at the top of the page, using [print_r($var, $return)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).
- `dvr($var, $return = false)` - displays information about a variable at the top of the page, using [var_dump($var, $return)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).
- `kpr($var, $return = false)` - displays the information about a variable at the top of the page using [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/).
- `dargs()` - displays information about the arguments of the current function at the top of the page using [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/).
- `dd($var, $label = null)` - writes the information about a variable in the file `drupal_debug.txt`, which is located in the temporary directory (admin/settings/file-system).
- `ddebug_backtrace()` - displays the call stack at the top of the page using [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/).
- `db_queryd($query, $args = array())` - this is a debug version of `db_query()`, which displays it at the top of the page after the execution of `$query`.
- `dpq($query, $return = FALSE, $name = NULL)` - this is an analog to the function `db_queryd()` only available in Drupal 7. Outputs SQL query using `dpm()` with substituted arguments. The first parameter takes an object DBTNG.

Comment: yeah but which one is more favorable to use. Do all of them output the same content

Comment: @JasjyotSinghJaswal The functions you mentioned on the question will output the same content in different formats. It will output whatever you put between (). The answer sais it all and even has links to php manual if you don't know what the function does. If you don't want to chose, go with krumo() and you'll be fine.